# Evenly distribute rows withing a group

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table `ITEMBANKITEMASSOCIATION` as

```
ID  FKITEMBANKID    FKITEMID
1   1               100
2   2               101
3   2               102
4   2               103
5   2               104
6   3               105
7   3               106
8   4               107
9   4               108
10  4               109
11  4               110
12  4               111
```

I want to select 10 rows but rows must to evenly distributed within `FKITEMBANKID`. That Means suppose I want 10 rows to select within 4 item banks, so 10/4 gives 2 items from each Item banks. This I have achieved by query

```
SELECT ITEMBANKITEMASSOCIATION.*
FROM   ITEMBANKITEMASSOCIATION INNER JOIN (
  SELECT   inIBA.FKITEMBANKID, GROUP_CONCAT(inIBA.FKITEMID) grouped_year
  FROM     ITEMBANKITEMASSOCIATION inIBA
  GROUP BY inIBA.FKITEMBANKID) group_max
  ON ITEMBANKITEMASSOCIATION.FKITEMBANKID = group_max.FKITEMBANKID
     AND FIND_IN_SET(ITEMBANKITEMASSOCIATION.FKITEMID, grouped_year) between 1 and 2
ORDER BY
  ITEMBANKITEMASSOCIATION.FKITEMBANKID DESC;
```

[Fiddle is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04c33f/2)

Result of this query gives only 7 rows, because this query select rows from each group (itembank) between 1 and 2. Still 3 rows are need to be pulled, how I can pull remaining 3 rows by distributing it in available itembanks? Available itembanks means after fetching first 7 exclude the pulled items and re-distribute within remaining banks.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  What is the logic for deciding which records get chosen for each group?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen MySQL 5.6. Currently random records should get selected for each group. Just I want it should be evenly distributed.

Comment: This could be tricky to handle in pre MySQL 8+.  I can't venture an answer myself.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oh! can you tell how this can be achieved in MySQL 8+. It will be great if make a fiddle so that I can understand better.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04c33f/9

Comment: @Strawberry hey, this looks great. Can you explain a bit about logic.

Comment: @Strawberry this working nice and as expected only the one thing is FKITEMID get selected are always same I want it to be selected randomly from each group. Can we do something for this?

Comment: Yep, you have to change one word of the code